# Find Volume of region that lies above unbounded region

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I just need help starting this problem. I need to create two iterated integrals, but I'm having a problem visualizing the graph to find the limits for them.

The function: z=e^(-x^2)

some other additional information is that it lies in the first quadrant between the lines y=x and y=0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base $B$ is the part of the first quadrant below the line $y=x$. Thus the volume is 
$$\iint_B e^{-x^2} \,dA.$$
We want to express this as an iterated integral. Something that works nicely is
$$\int_{x=0}^\infty \left(\int_{y=0}^x e^{-x^2}\,dy\right) dx.$$
The idea is that $dA=dx\,dy$, and to cover the region $B$, $y$ travels from $y=0$ to the line $y=x$, and then $x$ roams freely over all non-negative $x$. The integrations should be straightforward.

We could also imagine integrating first with respect to $x$. Not a good idea, we do not have a simple closed form antiderivative of $e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: Thanks, Your answer was very helpful! Thanks for making it simple to understand also! =]

Comment: You are welcome. For once I forgot to say draw a picture. I did, and probably could not solve the problem without it.